Is the difference between cubic and hexagonal diamond structure in 2 dimensions or 3 dimensions?
I was reading the book Solid State Physics by Charles Kittel. It was explained that the difference between Cubic F or FCC and the Hexagonal Closed Packed structure or the HCP was as follows -
(Please note that I know that atoms are 3 dimensional spherical entities but here when I say a dimension I am interested in how many directions the atoms are stacked)

Both have the same type of packing of atoms in 2 dimensions
The different placement of one 2D-layer above the other causes the structure to become FCC or HCP.
FCC follows an ABCABCABC type stacking in 3 dimensions
HCP follows ABABAB type stacking in 3 dimensions

Now for the Diamond structures,
It was explained that in cubic diamond the layers numbered 0,3,6... lie exactly above each other and in hexagonal diamond the layers 0,2,4,6.... lie exactly above each other. Hence Cubic Diamond was called 012012 type and Hexagonal Diamond was called 010101 type.
It was also mentioned in the caption of the figure depicting both these structures that these 012012 and 010101 structures are similar to FCC and HCP respectively.
But the figure hinted that the stacking difference between these 012012 and 010101 types was in the 2 dimensional stacking and not in the 3 dimensional stacking.
(Please note that I know that in diamond there are tetrahedrons which are 3 dimensional entities but I am assuming a tetrahedron to be a single entity and here when I say a dimension I am interested in how many directions the tetrahedrons are stacked)
So are the 012012 and 010101 stackings in 2 dimensions or are they in 3 dimensions?

Those are the packing orders in 3 dimensions. For fcc it is along the 111 direction, not well depicted by the conventional cubic unit cell.

Ok so both 012012 and 010101 are different in 3D and same in 2D. Thank you.

Cross posted on chemistry with an accepted answer.
